Pre-initialization of views?
It seems somewhere around the update to Xcode 16 and Swift 6, apple may have decided to change when view are initialized. My views suddenly pre-initialize before opening the view. Is this a new feature?
I have a regular VStack or a LazyVStack, with ForEach and Navigationlinks inside. Those views that the navigation link takes you to are initializing as I am scrolling in the VStack. This is absurd, there is so much overhead going on in these views to be initialized. I can think of a fix which is to implement init functions in the onAppear, and keep a property to track if view already appeared. But before that I just want to make sure this is a new feature and not some mishap on my part, and if there is a way to disable it.
Below you have two Views. HomeView is the parent view to PageTwo.
struct HomeView: View 
{ 
  init() 
  {
     print("Main View initialized") 
  } 
  var body: some View 
  { 
    NavigationStack { NavigationLink("Open") { PageTwo() } } 
  }
}

struct PageTwo: View 
{ 
  init() 
  { 
    print("Second View initialized") 
  }
  var body: some View 
  { 
    Text("")
  }
}


When HomeView appears, I get printouts of:

Main View initialized


Second View initialized

Both Views initialized even before I click Open to navigate me to the second view. This is did not happen before. I think around swift 6 update. Is this a bug or a feature? If a feature can it be disabled?
BTW: I have already asked this question on Apple Developer Forum with still no reply.

You should not make assumptions about when initialisers of your views will be called. SwiftUI has the liberty to call them whenever it likes.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/migrating-to-new-navigation-types

"There is so much overhead going on in these views to be initialized." Are you sure about that? Have you measured this with Instruments? Creating structs are typically very low-overhead. (This is also why you see structs everywhere in SwiftUI) You should not do heavy work in init in the first place. As you said, consider doing them in onAppear or similar.

I use the init() because it is simpler than onAppear then tracking state of view. The overhead I am talking about is a function inside a task that fetches documents from server, if its not in init, then its in onAppear, same thing.
Anyways, I have noticed that the auto pre-initialization also is inconsistent, ~sometimes~ some views, when I enter the view it inits, sometimes before I do.

"The overhead I am talking about is a function inside a task that fetches documents from server," That definitely should not be in init. SwiftUI is free to call init as many times as it likes. It doesn't even promise that the view will be displayed every time it calls init. Apple has been getting more aggressive on when they pre-warm things (this is hitting a lot of people when their app gets launched before the filesystem is even available), but there are no promises around this. If you mean "when it appears" it needs to be in onAppear, not init.


Apple has been getting more aggressive on when they pre-warm things
I have been observing what you have said, and now I know for sure. Thank you for clarifying things and your advice. Will be implementing something like onFirstAppear.

